# MySql affected_rows always 0 but UPDATE works

Tags: php, mysql

The following code in question always logs that the affected_rows was 0. I check my DB, the row updates fine everytime. Why is it 0?

```
public static function updateNextRunTime($nextRunTime)
    {
        $mysqli = new mysqli(GDB_HOST, GDB_USERNAME, GDB_PASSWORD, GDB_NAME);

        if ($mysqli->connect_errno)
        {
            throw new Exception('DB Connection Failed. Error Code: ' . $mysqli->connect_errno);
        }

        $cmd = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE balanceagent SET NextRunTime = ? WHERE Id = 1");
        if (!$cmd)
        {
            throw new Exception($mysqli->error);
        }

        $cmd->bind_param('s', $nextRunTime);
        $cmd->execute();

        $rows = $mysqli->affected_rows;

        $cmd->close();
        $mysqli->close();

        if ($rows != 1)
        {
            logToFile("Balance Agent Error - Failed to update the next run time! - Affected rows: " . $rows);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For prepared statements you should be using the [mysqli_stmt::affected_rows](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php) form :

```
$cmd->bind_param('s', $nextRunTime);
$cmd->execute();

$rows = $cmd->affected_rows;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your should check 
`$cmd->affected_rows;`
instead of 
`$mysqli->affected_rows;`

Comment: I've tried both. I put it back to $cmd, and still getting the affected_rows == 0.

Comment: are you logging it before the `$cmd->close(); $mysqli->close(); ` ?